Clickable/interactive SVG graphic in Compose
I was looking for answers on many forums and sites, and I can't find a way to make an interactive SVG graphic in Android Compose. There is one project that uses JavaScript and Compose Canvas, but it seems to be outdated.
For context, I want to create a sketch of human muscles and make it so on click a muscle group will change color.
One of my SVG files
I tried using Clickable and onClick, but drawPath() (in Canvas) doesn't have those properties. Is there another element that can create a vector graphic and detect its hit boxes, or maybe even something in Canvas? If not - how can I mathematically implement hit boxes for the SVG element? I have an idea to break down shapes and, for every one of them, make an approximate shape out of triangles and similar, not complicated figures. Then divide the screen into a few sectors for optimization, and by detecting which part of the screen was touched, determine what was clicked. Although I think it will still be suboptimal and laggy. Is there a better way?

You missed this site:    https://gomakethings.com/detecting-click-events-on-svgs-with-vanilla-js-event-delegation/

@Danny '365CSI' Engelman Isn't the article strictly about web development? I am trying to make a mobile app in android jetpack compose. I mentioned js only because of: https://medium.com/@scode43/interactive-svg-image-in-android-app-using-kotlin-and-javascript-6715c16397bb

Then its Google having the knowledge,, find their repo

the only way i can think of is to make svg for each muscle and recreate your image using column and row so you have control over it (color ,scale , click ,...)

you may wanna create Custom polygons for every muscle and gather them using Layout() composable
